# EclipseLink deserializes an empty entity object on remote EJB call

Tags: jpa, glassfish, eclipselink, jpa-2.1, glassfish-4.1

I am using the current release of GlassFish 4.1 with EclipseLink version 2.5.2 included.
At this GlassFish, I have an enterprise application and a web application deployed.
If an EJB that returns a loaded entity, is called from outside the GlassFish (like an external JavaFX application), the entity is returned properly.

But if the same EJB is called from the web application, the entity is not returned properly due to this bug [GLASSFISH-17432](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17432).

The workaround I already found here [Calling Remote EJB in EJB 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546656/calling-remote-ejb-in-ejb-3-1) is not really solving this problem, because if I disable the weaving in EclipseLink, the following does not work any more properly:

```java
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
public Foo getFoo() {
    return foo;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
public Bar getBar() {
    return bar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [static weaving](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving) as another workaround.

> Byte code weaving is a technique for changing the byte code of
>   compiled Java classes. You can configure byte code weaving to enable a
>   number of EclipseLink JPA performance optimizations, including support
>   for the lazy loading of one-to-one and many-to-one relationships,
>   attribute-level change tracking, and fetch groups.
>
> Weaving can be performed either dynamically when entity classes are
>   loaded, or statically as part of the build process.

([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/doc.1111/e16596/bestpractice.htm#CHDIJHAA))

As suggested in [GLASSFISH-16164](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16164) you can try the [eclipselink-staticweave-maven-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/eclipselink-staticweave-maven-plugin/). A detailed explanation about static weaving and the usage of the plugin (alternativly you can use ant) can be found in the [EclipseLink Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving#Use_the_Maven_plugin).

You then have to set this property in your `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
```

**See also:**

- [How to enable weaving in EclipseLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774965/how-to-enable-weaving-in-eclipselink)
- [Java-EE6: FetchType.LAZY with static weaving throws strange exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744179/java-ee6-fetchtype-lazy-with-static-weaving-throws-strange-exception)
- [Lazy loading does not works for ManyToOne in eclipselink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746259/lazy-loading-does-not-works-for-manytoone-in-eclipselink)
- [Why doesn't JPA's FetchType.LAZY work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505854/why-doesnt-jpas-fetchtype-lazy-work)

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I tried the static weaving by using the ant task. But the returned entities are still empty. I think there should be no difference in using ant or maven for static weaving, because bothe are using the same eclipselink binaries. Could it be that the problem resides in the combination of glassfish serializing / de-serializing and the eclipselink byte code enhanced entities ?